# Free file comparison tool for Windows, with simple interface similar to Kompare

Tags: windows, file-comparison

There's a ton of file comparison programs, but I'm looking for something specific and haven't found it yet.  I need a graphical file comparison tool for Windows, suitable for non-power users - it should have an intuitive, simple and non-overwhelming interface, showing differencies in a way similar to [this (Meld)](http://meldmerge.org/images/meld-mary.png) or [this (Kompare)](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blogmedia/kompare_rocks.jpeg).

It should be Free Software and it should have a simple Windows installer (so that inexperienced users can install it effortlessly).

Comment: @dave-rook: I know that questions that are "primarily opinion based" shouldn't be asked here.  But this question is not that much opinion based, I think: I listed specific requirements for the software.  In other words, I don't ask "what do you recommend?", but "what programs fit my description?".

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/).

for more alternatives see http://alternativeto.net/software/winmerge/?license=opensource.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: WinMerge is unfortunately old and abandoned and doesn't have a decent change detector nor a simple way to merge stuff. It does live on in forks but Meld and Kompare are miles ahead.